# ODT File created from text file take long time to open (10 min) . I keep the file locked somewhere I think on ReadLine

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I am reading for long time posts on here but first time that I post. I am struggling with an ODT file created that takes a lot to open. I've divided in small chunks and try debugging it but seems to be to the end of the patience.. After several hours of research I may believe that the issue is on reading the txt on ReadLine I am guessing . Your opinion is much appreciated. Here is the snippet of code:

```
public static void SolveLoadingTime(string path)
{

    string line;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    line = sr.ReadLine();
```

... some other code here

```
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        entries = line.Split('#');
        string nl = Environment.NewLine;

        Cell cell1 = new Cell(colData1);
        Cell cell2 = new Cell(colData2);
        Cell cell3 = new Cell(colData3);
        Cell cell4 = new Cell(colData4);

        Cell[] cells = new Cell[] { cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6, cell7 };
        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            cell.Style = "CellStyle1";
        }

        Row row1 = new Row();
        row1.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
        row1.Cells.Add(cell3);
        row1.Cells.Add(cell4);
        table1.Rows.Add(row1);
    }
```

Comment: What is an ODT file? A *lot* of files have that extension. If you try to read a line from a 300MB binary file that *doesn't* contain the newline bytes, you'll end up loading everything in memory

Comment: In any case you haven't provided enough information to understand what's going on. `StreamReader.ReadLine` isn't slow. Looping isn't slow. Your code doesn't make sense though - you read lines in a loop, split them but then ignore those values, adding the same `colData` values to a table, over and over.

Comment: after this `entries = line.Split('#');` your `entries` is just gone! where is it?

Comment: ODT is open text document.

Comment: I declared entries as an array of strings at the beginning of the class . And I use it to populate the cells with data from the txt file after I instantiate the cells.                var colData1 = entries[2];
                var colData2 = entries[21].Trim('"');
                var colData3 = entries[5].Trim('"');
                var colData4 = entries[38] + "," + nl + entries[39];
                var colData5 = entries[40] + "," + nl + entries[41];